# FreeBSD and HTTP Basic Authorization request for pkg install/update

Tags: freebsd

I set up a host for custom FreeBSD ports and I keep it HTTP Basic Auth and the problem associated with it.

You can see my pkg conf below, the question is: How do I add a user name and password to it for HTTP Basic Auth?

I already know **username:password@hostname.tld** usage but I'm looking for something more like

```
Header("Authorization", "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4zMjE")
```

how can I do that ? or you can suggest a better way to keep custom ports away from prying eyes :)

```
FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.MyCustomHost.tld/${ABI}/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  priority: 11,
  enabled: yes
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

pkg uses fetch(3) for fetching as documented in the manpage you can use ENVIRONMENT variables like HTTP_AUTH and HTTP_PROXY_AUTH